# Are abstract data types equivalent to types?

Tags: javascript, types

JavaScript essentially only has the type `Object` (with some optimizations for value types too, plus "absence" values). Under any circumstances can I be academically correct and describe a user-defined object as a type?

e.g.

```
function MyType() {}
MyType.prototype.myMethod = function() {}
```

Can `MyType` be thought of as a type - albeit one not recognized by a compiler?

Put another way - is the textbook definition of a type something that is recognized by a compiler, or can a type simply be thought of as something that has a certain interface?

Comment: This seems like more of a Programmers Exchange question, if it would even work there. As it stands, it is fairly opinion based.

Comment: OK, so there is no definitive answer? This is type theory and so should have an answer.

Comment: MyType will be an object where prototype and constructor wil differ from native Object type

Comment: @BenAston - In my opinion, the answer will be in the form of an argument in favor of or against MyType representing a type. For will argue that it exhibits the aspects of a type, against will argue it is just a plain object with properties. Not sure it has any bearing either way though.

Comment: You question is a bit opinionated as you can certainly think of it that way if you want. Ultimately you can think of you function as a constructor for a class whose shared instance methods you define at the prototype of the class. From a language perspective this is a function with properties.

Comment: Usually you would use "type" in quotes when describing a JavaScript "type" so that it is obvious you are not calling it a strongly typed object, but still recognize that it exhibits some of the behaviors of a strongly typed object. For the most part JavaScript "types" would be called weakly typed at best.

Comment: So the answer is that the definition of a type is fuzzy? Otherwise this has an answer.

Comment: I guess the question is what you are trying to achieve. You can call this concept a type if it helps you for your understanding or for explaining it to others, regardless of what the interpreter does. If you want to know what textbooks say - why not consulting one? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the body of your question is asking a different question than the title.  In an academic context, e.g. a data structures textbook, "abstract data type" refers to things like Linked Lists, Stacks, Binary Trees, etc.

These are not necessarily implemented in an Object Oriented language (in my Data Structures university course, we used C) -- they could consist of a group of structs an functions.  So to answer the question in your title, no they're not the same.

Comment: An abstract data type such as "linked-list" defines a data structure with either similar behavior or similar semantics. "An abstract data type is defined only by the operations that may be performed on it and by mathematical pre-conditions and constraints on the effects (and possibly cost) of those operations. " Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type. `function Foo() {} Foo.prototype.myMethod = function() {}` defines an albeit simple data structure: an abstract data type. Or, abbreviated, a type.